# send 2 variables onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a while loop statement to echo some information from the database. every loop has a button. When I click on that button i want to send 2 value's and have an update function with those 2 value. So far I have been getting only 1. The other one is blank. I want to get the id's via javascript or normal href=""  this is my while loop

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $productimg = $row["Product_Image"];
    $productname = $row["Product_Name"];
    $price = $row["Product_Price"];
    $quantity = $row["Quantity"];
    $seller = $row["Product_Seller"];
    $cartid = $row["Cart_ID"];
    $newimg = str_replace(' ', '%20', $productimg);
    echo "<div class='cartcontent'>";
    echo "<div class='s1'><a href='itemview.php?ID=$productname'><img src=$newimg /></a></div>";
    echo "<div class='s2'><div class='s2t'><a href='itemview.php?ID=$productname'>$productname </a> &nbsp; <h2>Sold By $seller</h2></div><div class='s2b'><a href='?deletecartid=$cartid'>Delete</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href='?saveforlaterid=$cartid'>Save for later</a></div></div>";
    echo "<div class='s3'>$price</div>";
    echo "<div class='s4'>";
    include 'itemquantity.php';//this page class="qty2"
    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?updateid=$cartid?quant=".$_GET['qty2']."'>Update</a>";//this is what i am struggling with
    echo "</div></div>";
    echo "?updateid=$cartid?quant=".$_GET['test']."";//just to see what i am getting
    $count++;
}
```

I even tried getting a value from javascript for the onchange method from the dropdownlist inside the itemquantity.php which its class is qty2.

```
function getquant(){
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("qty2")[0];
var qty = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
alert(qty);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = qty;
};
```

And this is the isset get function

```
if(isset($_GET['updateid'])){
$updateid = $_GET['updateid'];
$updatequant = $_GET['quant'];
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE cart SET Quantity = '$updatequant' WHERE Cart_ID = '$updateid'");}
```

I've seen some info's around about XMLhtml and cookie but they somewhat did not work so I have no idea what else to do lol.

If anyone knows how or has a working method, would be appreciated!

EDIT: Just to clarify the $_GET['qty2'] is inside the itemquantity.php(which is included in my while loop) it is a dropdownlist.
this is what itemquantity.php looks like

```
<select placeholder='quantity' class='qty2' id='qty2' onchange="getquant()" value='<?php print_r($cartid);?>'>
        <option value='1' <?php if ($quantity == '1') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>1</option>
        <option value='2' <?php if ($quantity == '2') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>2</option>
        <option value='3' <?php if ($quantity == '3') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>3</option>
        <option value='4' <?php if ($quantity == '4') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>4</option>
        <option value='5' <?php if ($quantity == '5') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>5</option>
        <option value='6' <?php if ($quantity == '6') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>6</option>
        <option value='7' <?php if ($quantity == '7') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>7</option>
        <option value='8' <?php if ($quantity == '8') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>8</option>
        <option value='9' <?php if ($quantity == '9') echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>9</option>
```

the dropdown list is in a get method with class='qty2' id='qty2' onchange="getquant()" value='

Answer (score 0):

By stopping the PHP parser before putting in static HTML you can more easily solve this problem.

Here's how you should have written the code for the `loop`

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $productimg = $row["Product_Image"];
    $productname = $row["Product_Name"];
    $price = $row["Product_Price"];
    $quantity = $row["Quantity"];
    $seller = $row["Product_Seller"];
    $cartid = $row["Cart_ID"];
    $newimg = str_replace(' ', '%20', $productimg);

    // end PHP processor
    ?>  
     <div class='cartcontent'>
     <div class='s1'><a href='itemview.php?ID=<?php print_r($productname);?>'>
     <img src='<?php print_r($newimg);?>' /></a></div>

    etc etc.

    <?php
     // now start the PHP processor again and finish out the loop


       $count++;
     }
```

---

the problem with the line containing this:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='?updateid=$cartid?quant=".$_GET['qty2']."'>Update</a>
```

is that  your doing  `?updateid=$cartid?quant=`  which should be

`?updateid=$cartid&quant=`

multiple query values should be separated with an `&`, as the `?`  only belongs at the beginning of a query string

Comment: Sorry about the ? and &'s but i had that already. perhaps maybe because i pressed ctrl + z so many times it went back to that without noticing.

Anyways i am still getting this in my browser

cart.php?updateid=11&quant=

quant is still empty for some reason